# Tensorflow with Eager Execution: DDPG - Apply Action Gradient to Actor

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient, reinforcement-learning, eager-execution

I am struggling to apply the Tensorflow eager execution (TF2) in order to train the actor of the actor-critic [DDPG algorithm](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02971.pdf). The description in [this example](https://nervanasystems.github.io/coach/components/agents/policy_optimization/ddpg.html) explains:

> Use the actor’s online network to get the action mean values using the current states as the inputs. Then, use the critic online network in order to get the gradients of the critic output with respect to the action mean values ∇aQ(s,a) | s=s_t,a=μ(s_t). Using the chain rule, calculate the gradients of the actor’s output, with respect to the actor weights, given ∇aQ(s,a). Finally, apply those gradients to the actor network.

Actor and Critic are both Keras models. Apologies for not posting the complete code, though I hope my problem is comprehensible from these relevant snippets.

```
def fit_actor(self, state):

    action = self.predict_actor(state)              #online actor
    q_value = self.predict_critic(state, action)    #online critic

    param_gradient = self.tape_online_critic.gradient(q_value, [action]) 
    #=> is alway [None], also for tape_online_actor

    gradient = zip(param_gradient, self.online_actor.trainable_weights)

    self.optimizer_actor.apply_gradients(gradient)
```

and in 'predict_critic' the critic is fed with the state and action so 'tape_online_critic' has operations

```
#for online critic and online actor
def predict_critic(self, state, actions):

    with self.tape_online_critic as tape:
        return self.online_critic([state, actions])


def predict_actor(self, state):

    with self.tape_online_actor as tape:
        return self.online_actor([state])
```

I tried almost every thinkable combination of variables/tapes etc. but I always a gradient of **[None]** and a **ValueError**.

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv2d_2/kernel:0']
```

1. I am unsure about the order of the arguments for the [tape.gradient()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#gradient) function or even the nature of the arguements itself.
2. As I understand, I have to call the [tape.gradient()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#gradient) function on the tape of the online actor in order to get the gradient for the weights of the actor with respect to the operations recorded in the predict_actor function within the with tape: context. Do I additionally have to [tape.watch(*someTensor*)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#watch) something there? The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) says variables are automatically watched, so I'd assume no.
3. Is tf.GradientTape even the right thing to use here? There is also tfe.gradients_function?

Comment: Why does `predict_critic` return the prediction in the scope of `self.tape_online_critic`? It's hard to give you a clear answer when we're unable to see the code. Have you tried looking at [TF Custom Gradient walkthrough](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training_walkthrough) ?It would be helpful for everyone (yourself included) if you came up with a ssimplified example that we can run